# How can pitot tubes give us local velocity in a flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

I am studying about static pressure,dynamic pressure and the principle behind pitot tube.

However in pitot tubes we apply Bernoulli equation between two points which are not on the same streamline. So this should not work for rotational flows. I understand that the very application of Bernoulli equation requires there be no friction and hence no viscosity. So if the fluid was not rotating beforehand it has to be irrotational for us to apply Bernoulli equation.

Is there any way to do this for a rotational flow with or without viscous effects.

Comment: You can measure the stagnation pressure with PITOT tube, if the flow is rotational then it does't make any sense to measure stagnation pressure by applying the Bernoulli, because bernoulli equation is not applicable, you always have viscous forces.

Comment: Edited - changed spelling to "pitot."

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Bernoulli is still applicable. As the OP mentioned, it must be taken along stream lines. There is a separate crossflow equation for rotational flow, where the pressure gradient perpendicular to the stream lines is calculated. So use Bernoulli to arrive at a convenient place to make the hop, then traverse stream lines, then use Bernoulli once again to arrive at the destination. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-25-advanced-fluid-mechanics-fall-2013/inviscid-flow-and-bernoulli/MIT2_25F13_Equation_of_Mo.pdf